# Using .map function to create hashes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an array `[5,2,6,4]` and I would like to create a structure such as the first minus the second etc until the last row.

I have tried using map, but not sure how to proceed since i might need indxes.

I would like to store the result in something that looks like:

```
{1 => (5, 2, 3), 2 =>(2,6,-4), 3 => (6,4,2)}
```

So an array of `x` should return `x-1` hashes.
Anybody knows how to do? should be a simple one. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you want to work with the array elements in pairs: `5,2`, `2,6`, ... That means you want to use [`each_cons`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_cons):

```
a.each_cons(2) { |(e1, e2)| ... }
```

Then you'll want the index to get the `1`, `2`, ... hash keys; that suggests throwing a [`Enumerator#with_index`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerator.html#method-i-with_index) into the mix:

```
a.each_cons(2).with_index { |(e1, e2), i| ... }
```

Then you can use [`with_object`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerator.html#method-i-with_object) to get the final piece (the hash) into play:

```
a.each_cons(2).with_index.with_object({}) { |((e1, e2), i), h| h[i + 1] = [e1, e2, e1 - e2] }
```

If you think all the parentheses in the block's arguments are too noisy then you can do it in steps rather than a single one-liner.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `each_index`:

```rb
a = [5, 2, 6, 4]
h = {}
a[0..-2].each_index { |i| h[i+1] = [a[i], a[i+1], a[i] - a[i+1]] } 
h
 => {1=>[5, 2, 3], 2=>[2, 6, -4], 3=>[6, 4, 2]}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use

```
 each_with_index
```

Suppose you have an array:

```
arr = [3,[2,3],4,5]
```

And you want to covert with hash(key-value pair). 'Key' denotes an index of an array and 'value' denotes value of an array. Take a blank hash and iterate with each_with_index and pushed into the hash and finally print the hash.

Try this:

```
hash={}

arr.each_with_index do |val, index|
    hash[index]=val
end

p hash
```

Its output will be:

```
{0=>3, 1=>[2, 3], 2=>4, 3=>5}
```

If you want that index always starts with 1 or 2 etc then use

```
arr.each.with_index(1) do |val, index|
    hash[index] = val
end
```

Output will be:

```
{1=>3, 2=>[2, 3], 3=>4, 4=>5}
```